# Incorrect of getting the average value of an array of numbers

Tags: perl

I have a rather stupid question.

**the input data:**

---

```
    No:20   2.23    5.5   101   404   26.3
    No:01   2.40    5.3   100   404   25.7
    No:02   2.30    5.6   100   405   25.4
    No:03   2.39    5.3   100   404   25.5

    No:07   2.61    4.9   100   404   25.4
    No:08   2.53   
    No:09   2.41    5.4   101   404   25.4
    No:10   2.59    5.  100   404   25.4
    No:11   2.55    5.4   101   404   25.3
    No:12   2.3    5.3   100   404   25.5
    No:13   2.47    5.2   100   404   25.
    No:14   2.25    5.1   100   404   25.6
    No:15   2.24    5.1   100   404   25.7

    No:17   2.57    5.0   100   404   25.5
    No:18   2.45    5.2   101   404   25.5
    No:04   2.51    5.5   100   404   25.4
    No:05   2.38    5.1   101   405   25.5No:04   2.51    5.5   100   404   25.4
    No:06   2.29    5.1   100   405   25.3
    No:07   2.53    4.9   100   404   25.4
    No:08   2.41    5.2   100   404   25.5
    No:07   2.46    4.9   100   404   27.6
    No:05   2.23    5.1   100   404   25.0��
    o:09   2.39    5.3   100   404   26.4
    No:01   2.49    5.3   101   404   26.8
    No:02   2.21    5.5   101   404   26.2
```

______________________________________and more

**I want to get each hundred of the end of line element average.**

```
#!usr/bin/perl
use utf8;
while(<>){
    if(/^No:\d{2}\s{3}     \d\.\d{2}s{4}    \d\.\d\s{3}    \d{3}s{3}    \d{3}s{3}    \d{2}\.\d\s$/x){
        chomp;
        push @Array,[split/\s+/];
    }
}

foreach (0..$#Array/100){
    my $average=0;
    $average += $Array[$_][5]/100   foreach($_..$_+100);
    print "this is   $average \n";
}
```

**output(the average)**

```
23.836
26.5630000000001
26.462
26.462
26.361
26.462
26.5630000000001
29.694
26.664
26.967
```

**use MS Excel **

```
25.9530
25.4850
25.7610
25.3160
25.1650
25.7060
25.9500
25.6800
25.4720
25.4820
```

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: Presumably your problem is that your function is giving different values than Excel returns. As a first step, try doing a much smaller problem, say 10 rows total and taking an average every 5 rows. Then you can manually calculate the answer to decide whether your function or (the way you used) Excel is incorrect.

Comment: What are you talking about? For the program and data you provided, the output is actually `this is   0`. Please fix your question.

Answer (score 0):

You are going through the data wrongly.  On your first pass you look at values 0-99 and then on the second pass you look at 1-100, then 2-101, etc.  It sounds like you want to do 0-99 then 100-199 and so on which you could do with something like:

```
my $chunks = $#Array / 100;

foreach my $chunk (0 .. $chunks) {
    my $low = 100 * $chunk;
    my $high = $low + 100;
    $high = $#Array if $high > $#Array;
    my $sum = 0;
    foreach my $n ($low .. $high) {
         $sum += $Array[$n][5];
    }
    my $avg = $sum/($high - $low);
    print "avg=$avg\n";
}
```